# What determines the type of takedown animation performed?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I noticed that most of the lethal take-downs I performed in my recent play through involved stabbing the enemy in the lower section and then splitting their head with the elbow blade as they were doubled over.

Only once, in the entire gameplay with over 100 take-downs, did I see the one where he extends his fingers, grab the enemy by the top of their head, and snap their neck with a nasty looking twist.

Obviously the take-down animation isn't random or else I'd see that maneuver more, but what determines the animation?  Distance?  Approach?  Type of enemy?

Is it possible to do a double take-down with the neck twist animation?  I'd like to capture a video of Jensen doing that against two Ogres(the super heavy soldiers) if possible.

Comment: I wonder if it is worth retitling this question to refer to the takedown *animation*, not *type*, because I assumed from the title that you were going to be asking about non-lethal vs lethal.

Comment: I always use non-lethal, and sometimes it's a straight punch to the face, others it's a tap on the shoulder and a smack when they turn (and so on). It *could* feasibly be related to the position and orientation of the target, because the shoulder tap anim would be a stupid one to use if they were *facing* me when I hit the button.

Comment: It may depend on the stance of the person being taken down, for example different animations play for sitting targets (obviously).

Comment: @dma I get "tap-and-smack" all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First if you have double takedown the animation is first chosen by **number** of opponents.

Second by the **type** of takedown(lethal or no).

Third the way targets are **facing**(facing you,facing away,side or sitting).

Fourth is the **random** chosen animation(not shure but it seems some animation have higher chance of being randomized).

Note:Animations for heavy enemies are same.Bosses counter your takedowns.

-About your case of double neck twist takedown i belive it is not possible.Here are most of animations:

Comment: Also, there's a different one if the victim is sitting.

Comment: interesting video, but I also note he didn't try any moves on bigger enemies

Comment: It seems (Nonlethal + Behind + "Heavy" enemy guards) almost always turns into a "tap on the shoulder, punch in the face" animation, except that they're taller so that it becomes a punch in the chest instead.

Comment: that's too bad, the neck twist on a heavy would look awesome